# To stop the user from opening multiple tabs of same website in react JS

Tags: reactjs, window

I am using localstorage for a user details  for my website but when there are multiple tabs opens with different user then it mismatch the details of users. So I want to restrict the user  by allowing only one instance of the website at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going about this in a different way. Store your user details in localstorage behind a unique identifier derived from the logged in user. Perhaps the (hash of) the id, or if unique the username. That way you can always retrieve the relevant credentials of the logged in user.

Comment: It fetches other API details  on different pages - then how will I differentiate which user called API.

Comment: If you store the user data behind an unique identifier you can always retrieve that data by checking the current logged in user, determine the unique identifier and get the data. I'm assuming the API is always called by the logged in user per tab.